# Unable to iterate through JSONArray

Tags: java, json, eclipse, io, arrays

I am having a JSON file, which look like below.

```
[
    {
        "_type": "ArticleItem",
        "body": "But under Obamacare, many can find plans in the $50 to $70 range, he said.",
        "title": "Who's signing up for Obamacare? - Jan. 13, 2014",
        "source": "money.cnn.com",
        "last_crawl_date": "2014-01-14",
        "url": "http://money.cnn.com/2014/01/13/news/economy/obamacare-enrollment/index.html"
    },
    {
        "_type": "ArticleItem",
        "body": "debut on January 25 at the Daytona International Speedway.",
        "title": "GM reveals 625-horsepower Corvette Z06 - Jan. 13, 2014",
        "source": "money.cnn.com",
        "last_crawl_date": "2014-01-14",
        "url": "http://money.cnn.com/2014/01/13/autos/chevrolet-corvette-z06/index.html"
    }
]
```

This is just a sample, original final contains million of records. I need to iterate through this, and print the title and body. This is what I did.

```
 public void createHash()
    {
        AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
        Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
        s3.setRegion(usWest2);

        strBuffer = new StringBuffer("");

        try
        {
            //List all the Buckets
            List<Bucket>buckets = s3.listBuckets();

            for(int i=0;i<buckets.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println("- "+(buckets.get(i)).getName());
            }


            //Downloading the Object
            System.out.println("Downloading Object");
            S3Object s3Object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("JsonBucket", "Articles_4.json"));
            System.out.println("Content-Type: "  + s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());


            //Read the JSON File
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent()));
            while (true) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null) break;

               // System.out.println("    " + line);
                strBuffer.append(line);
                //System.out.println(line);
            }

            JSONTokener jTokener = new JSONTokener(strBuffer.toString());
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jTokener);



            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject insideLoopObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                System.out.println("Printing JSON Title.........");
                System.out.println(insideLoopObject.getString("title"));
                System.out.println("Printing Body.........");
                System.out.println(insideLoopObject.getString("body"));
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, what this does is, printing the same JSON Object again and again, it is not iterating. I know the way I extracted JSON is correct, because I can manually print one by one, just like this.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
```

So, what is wrong with my code? Pleas help.

Comment: is it possible the result is a string and needs an `eval()`?  I have not worked with AWS before.   :(

Comment: Can you show us an example of the output? It works for me.